# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm making an application that can search a table 'employee' and return results. I'm using searchdialog for searching. But I gets FC on pressing the search button on search dialog. Please help me out.

Code :

```
public class SimpleSearch extends ListActivity {
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    protected String query;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          doMySearch(query);
          }
        }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                  new String[]{"%" + query + "%"});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.emp_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Error, stack trace :

```
shortMsg:java.lang.NullPointerException
longMsg:java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simple.search/com.simple.search.SimpleSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
stackTrace:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.simple.search/com.simple.search.SimpleSearch}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.simple.search.SimpleSearch.onCreate(SimpleSearch.java:34)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
... 11 more
```

Databasehelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test_diectory";

    protected Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "1", 2000).show();
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(s);
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your cursor getCount()? debug it..

Comment: can you please explain how to do it? I'm new to eclipse and android.

Comment: line 34 is doMySearch(query);

Comment: also error at   `cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?",`

Comment: So where is your `db` declared and initialized ?

Comment: See, in your `SimpleSearch` you have a  `protected SQLiteDatabase db;` where did you initialize it..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5439/discussion-between-binoy-babu-and-adil-soomro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to adil. Looks like I forgot initialize the db. Adding `db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();` fixed the error.